# Access global document from shadow DOM script

Tags: javascript, svg, shadow-dom

I have the following svg. Of course document.body is always null because it refers to shadow DOM. Is it possible to access global document from this script?

Please don't tell me it doesn't make sense, believe me it does.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="266" height="100" viewBox="0 0 266 100"
    overflow="visible" enable-background="new 0 0 266 100" xml:space="preserve">
    <g><rect fill="#3B5998" width="266" height="100"/></g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M242.2011719,66.1777344c1.4726562,0,2.6464844,1.2011719,2.6464844,2.7011719
            c0,1.5234375-1.1738281,2.7109375-2.6572266,2.7109375c-1.4755859,0-2.6728516-1.1875-2.6728516-2.7109375
            c0-1.5,1.1972656-2.7011719,2.6728516-2.7011719H242.2011719z M242.1904297,66.5976562
            c-1.1865234,0-2.1582031,1.0214844-2.1582031,2.28125c0,1.2832031,0.9716797,2.2910156,2.1689453,2.2910156
            c1.1982422,0.0117188,2.1552734-1.0078125,2.1552734-2.2792969s-0.9570312-2.2929688-2.1552734-2.2929688H242.1904297z
             M241.6865234,70.4511719h-0.4804688V67.4375c0.2519531-0.0351562,0.4921875-0.0703125,0.8515625-0.0703125
            c0.4560547,0,0.7539062,0.0957031,0.9365234,0.2265625c0.1767578,0.1328125,0.2724609,0.3359375,0.2724609,0.6230469
            c0,0.3984375-0.2617188,0.6367188-0.5849609,0.734375v0.0234375c0.2626953,0.0488281,0.4423828,0.2871094,0.5029297,0.7304688
            c0.0703125,0.46875,0.1425781,0.6484375,0.1904297,0.7460938h-0.5029297
            c-0.0712891-0.0976562-0.1435547-0.3730469-0.2041016-0.7695312c-0.0703125-0.3828125-0.2636719-0.5273438-0.6484375-0.5273438
            h-0.3330078V70.4511719z M241.6865234,68.7832031h0.3476562c0.3935547,0,0.7285156-0.1445312,0.7285156-0.5175781
            c0-0.2636719-0.1904297-0.5273438-0.7285156-0.5273438c-0.1572266,0-0.265625,0.0117188-0.3476562,0.0234375V68.7832031z"/>
    </g>
    <script>console.log(document.body)</script>
</svg>
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh, it does. I need to add an event listener to the global document from this script. Like a spy svg.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I _think_ `window.top.document.body` should work from the script in your external SVG. If it does, I am happy to add this as an answer below.

Comment: Yes, @Rounin, it worked. Thank you very much! Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access the global document from a script in your external SVG file.

Your access is via:

```
window.top.document.body
```